# Does anyone know of a program or script to show which route is being used for an IP address?

Tags: ip-routing

In Windows (say Windows 10), I'd like to put in an address, and then the relevant line from the routing table is shown (if any). So, pretend you are pinging an address and the computer processes the routing table and figures out which route to use. It would also be nice for the program to show which of the various network adapters/interfaces it would use. That way, if I suspect there is a routing issue, I can quickly figure out if there is a route and if so, is that the route I would expect. With modern configurations having like 80 lines in the routing table and multiple physical adapters as well as VPN adapters and such, there can be a lot to look through to figure out what's happening.

Comment: You don't like tracert? https://ss64.com/nt/tracert.html

Comment: I don't understand. Tracert shows responses from endpoints as a packet actually traverses a network. I'm talking about the routing table on my machine.

Comment: ...which determines the first hop shown in tracert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress <destination>
```

or somewhat similar to the `route print` output:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress <destination> | Format-Table -Property DestinationPrefix,NextHop,InterfaceAlias
```